# How to correctly split a div in columns and rows

Tags: html, css

I need to create a `div` structure made in this way:

[image]

This is what I've done:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
#all {
  background: black;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
#leftUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
#leftDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: indigo;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
#center {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 620px;
}
#centerUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
#centerDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 620px;
  height: 620px;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
}
#rightUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #9ACD32;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
#rightDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">

  <div id="left">
    <div id="leftUp">
      <div id="selector">
        <form id="abcd">
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Bringing Down the House" checked>Bringing Down the House
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Metropolis">Metropolis
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Fight Club">Fight Club
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Ciclope Festival">Ciclope Festival 2014
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Long Kiss Goodnight">The Long Kiss Goodnight
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Date Night">Date Night
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Slums of Beverly Hills">The Slums of Beverly Hills
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="center">
    <div id="centerUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="centerDown" with="620px" heigth="620px">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrrpa428/)

What I get is different from what I'd like. Why? How can I fix?

If possible, I would like to keep all those `divs` because I need them (I need to add some information).

Comment: A very quick demo using [positioning](https://jsfiddle.net/zrrpa428/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may imbricate flex boxes :

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
#all {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  /* demo purpose to show element stretch behavior */
}
#left {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
#leftUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
#leftDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: indigo;
  flex: 1;
  ;
  padding: 5px;
}
#center {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}
#centerUp {
  background-color: orange;
}
#centerDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
}
#rightUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #9ACD32;
  flex: 1;
}
#rightDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">

  <div id="left">
    <div id="leftUp">
      <div id="selector">
        <form id="abcd">
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Bringing Down the House" checked>Bringing Down the House
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Metropolis">Metropolis
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Fight Club">Fight Club
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Ciclope Festival">Ciclope Festival 2014
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Long Kiss Goodnight">The Long Kiss Goodnight
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Date Night">Date Night
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Slums of Beverly Hills">The Slums of Beverly Hills
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="center">
    <div id="centerUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="centerDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `flexbox`

Note that I tweaked your code a bit, for example, removed `float:left`in CSS, removed the deprecated `width`/`height` HTML tags, and deleted duplicated properties, joining in one rule.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
#all {
  background: black;
  display: flex
}
#left {
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1
}
#leftUp,
#leftDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
#leftUp {
  background-color: pink;
}
#leftDown {
  background-color: indigo;
}
#center {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 620px;
}
#centerUp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
#centerDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 20px)
}
#right {
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
  flex: 1
}
#rightUp,
#rightDown {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
#rightUp {
  background-color: #9ACD32;
}
#rightDown {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="leftUp">
      <div id="selector">
        <form id="abcd">
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Bringing Down the House" checked>Bringing Down the House
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Metropolis">Metropolis
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Fight Club">Fight Club
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Ciclope Festival">Ciclope Festival 2014
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Long Kiss Goodnight">The Long Kiss Goodnight
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Date Night">Date Night
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Slums of Beverly Hills">The Slums of Beverly Hills
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <div id="centerUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="centerDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm centerDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightUp">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightUp</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDown">
      <p>Hi, I'm rightDown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reason you don't get what do you expect with your sample.

First all the floating panel should be called before you centered panel.

Then if the size of your center panel is biger than the page size it will return to the line.

for the center panel only change the css class by :

```
#center {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
        background: red;
        width: 30%;
        position:absolute;
        }
```

I advice you to manipulate the with of your panel with percent.
I put 30% in my sample but only to let you choose the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about content hierarchy:

```css
body {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
   }
   
   p {
    margin: 0
   }

   #all {
    background: black;
   }

   #left {
    float: left; 
    padding: 5px;
    background: blue;
    width: 200px; 
   }
   
   #leftUp {
     box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 5px; 
   }

   #leftDown {
     box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: indigo;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
   }

   #center {
    display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
    /* width: 620px; */
   }

   #centerUp {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
   }

   #centerDown {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* width: 620px; */
    height: 620px;
   }

   #right {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background: green;
   }

   #rightUp {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #9ACD32;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
   }

   #rightDown {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
   }
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="all">

    <div id="left">
      <div id="leftUp">
        <div id="selector">
          <form id="abcd">
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Bringing Down the House" checked>Bringing Down the House<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Metropolis">Metropolis<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Fight Club">Fight Club<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Ciclope Festival">Ciclope Festival 2014<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Long Kiss Goodnight">The Long Kiss Goodnight<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="Date Night">Date Night<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ab" value="The Slums of Beverly Hills">The Slums of Beverly Hills
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="leftDown">
        <p>Hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown, hi, I'm leftDown</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="right">
      <div id="rightUp">
        <p>Hi, I'm rightUp</p>
      </div>
      <div id="rightDown">
        <p>Hi, I'm rightDown</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="center">
      <div id="centerUp">
        <p>Hi, I'm centerUp</p>
      </div>
      <div id="centerDown" with="620px" heigth="620px">
        <p>Hi, I'm centerDown</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I also don't know about your dimensions preferences...